# How to filter this string in PHP?

Tags: php, filter

How to filter the numbers `2968` of the string `a:1:{i:0;s:4:"2968";}` in PHP?

The number `2968` can be another number, so please make it to filter from `00000` to `99999`.

Comment: `2968` != `00000 to 99999`.

Comment: As this is serialised data, why not use `unserialize()` to convert the string into an array and fetch it that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This string is a [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array. You should [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it and then iterate the array or access the known index you need:

```
$your_string = 'a:1:{i:0;s:4:"2968";}';
$unserialized_array = unserialize( $your_string );
echo $unserialized_array[0]; // Echoes 2968
```

Comment: Sweet, thank you very much!